# Sails socket requests log undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

Not *really* a problem, but kind of bothers me; After launching my app, all socket requests (e.g. `/api/articles/subscribe`) logs `undefined` to console, as such:

```
GET /api/articles 200 180.463 ms - 27767
GET /api/articles/subscribe undefined - ms - -
```

The first request is HTTP, the second is socket.

Why is this and how can I fix that?

**Edit**
My routes:

```
'get /api/articles': 'ArticlesController.index',
'/api/articles/subscribe': 'ArticlesController.subscribe',
```

I'm using the GET route (`GET /api/articles`) to get all my articles in JSON format. While viewing the articles I subscribe to a specific room via

```
io.socket.get('/api/articles/subscribe', function(data, jwt) { ...
```

The subscribe method itself

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
  if(typeof req.user !== 'undefined') {
    sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'articles');

    return res.ok();
  }
}
```

Subscribing works well, but there's always this `GET /api/articles/subscribe undefined - ms - -` in my console.

Comment: Can you add a bit more info?  If I make a very basic Sails app from scratch it doesn't log anything to the console (e.g.  sails new article; cd article; sails generate api article; sails lift)

Comment: @Ultrasaurus edited the question to provide more info.

Comment: Are you using `res.getHeader('X-Response-Time')` to print response time?

Comment: These log entries are created automatically by Sails. I didn't anything to log requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the following?

This is when you use **Get** request (e.g. http://www.url.com/?user=randomusername)

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
  var user = req.param("user");
  if(user !== undefined) {
    sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'articles');
    return res.ok();
  }
  return res.badRequest();
}
```

This is when you use a **Post** request (e.g. if you send JSON or similar)

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
  if(req.body !== undefined && req.body.user !== undefined) {
    sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'articles');
    return res.ok();
  }
  return res.badRequest();
}
```

Or you need to use it like this (according to [Sails reference](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/join))

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
 if (!req.isSocket) {
   return res.badRequest();
 }
 var room = req.param('user');
 sails.sockets.join(req, room, function(err) {
   if (err) {
     return res.serverError(err);
   }
   return res.json({
     message: 'Subscribed to a room called '+ room +'!'
   });
 });
}
```